# SQL syntax error with psycopg2 (python)

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.6, psycopg2

So I'm attempting to write my own sqlite3 to postgresql migration script, which takes all the tables from one database to another.

I'm currently seeing the following syntax error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "'name'"
LINE 1: UPDATE django_site SET ('name', 'domain')=('127.0.0.1:8080',...
                                ^
```

It's not quite liking `('name', 'domain')` ... I'm perhaps thinking there's something subtle I'm missing...

`('name', 'domain')` is generated from the following line of code:

```
col = tuple([desc[0] for desc in self.cur_sql3.description])
```

i.e., taking all of the column names as a generated `list` then converting to `tuple` type.

And the SQL query is currently being built as such:

```
cur_psql.execute("UPDATE {0} SET {1}={2} WHERE id={3}".format(table[0], col[1:], row[1:], col[0]))
```

`table[0]` is the **table name**, `col[1:]` is everything but the primary id key, `row[1:]` are all the row values minus the primary key, and col[0] is the **primary key value**, e.g., `1,2,3,4` or `5` etc

Any obvious tips to avoid this issue?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `'` from the column names? I don't think they are allowed for columns.

Comment: When I do I get “current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block”

Comment: Probably because your current transaction is aborted, and your commands are ignored until the end of the transaction. End the transaction (`ROLLBACK`) and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to split this into separate SQL statements or you'll need to do some kind of looping over your column value pairs.  I would need more information to write the corrected Python code, but your SQL should look something like this:

`UPDATE table SET col = val WHERE id = id_val`

You're doing something like:

`UPDATE table SET ('col1', 'col2') = ('val1', 'val2')`

If you want to update multiple columns in one statement, you'd do this:

`UPDATE table SET col1 = val1, col2 = val2 WHERE id = id_val`

Keep in mind you'll need to escape your values if they're character columns (but not if they're numeric), like so:

`UPDATE table SET col1 = 'character value', col2 = 123 WHERE id = 1`

Ultimately, this should be accomplished with bind variables rather than string formatting, as string formatting can expose your code to SQL injection attacks (might not be a concern if this is strictly a utility script that you're running yourself but it's a good habit to get into regardless).  You can find the documentation for bind variables in psycopg2 here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

Following my advice above would result in something like this:

```
set_clauses = ",".join(["{} = %s".format(col) for col in col[1:]])
query = "update {} set {} where id = {}".format(table[0], set_clauses, row[0])
cur_psql.execute(query, row[1:])
```

Comment: I guess I could look over and make two update transactions, which is more efficient?

Comment: The [Postgrsql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html) explicitly mentions the parenthesis syntax so I don't think that thats the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @syntonym I wasn't aware of that syntax in postgres.  My guess would be that single quoting the column names within the parens is causing the syntax error then (that's where the column cursor in the error message points)

Comment: @msiadak I feel like we're getting closer but I get the following syntax error: `set_clauses = ",".join([{} = %s for col in col[1:]])` and it is pointing to the `=` ...?

Comment: Sorry, I hit save too quickly on my edit.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: Even closer: `PostgreSQL: Cursor execution error!
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

Comment: Are you doing this in an interactive session?  You may need to create a new cursor or start a new transaction.

Comment: Ignore me, I wasn't closing the current cursor because I was commiting the cursor and not the connection! derp! Thank you for all your help! Follow me on twitter @michealjroberts I'd like to propose a reward

Comment: @msiadak Hi, just another question ... How would I go about constructing the same `set_values` method for this execution command: `cur_psql.execute("INSERT INTO {0} {1} VALUES {2} WHERE id={3}".format(table[0], col[1:], row[1:], col[0]))` ??

Comment: I think you're going to want row[0] at the end, otherwise you'll be doing WHERE id = id (which will match all rows).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166428/discussion-between-michael-roberts-and-msiadak).